# Send POST request using fetch Type Error: Failed to fetch

Tags: javascript, camunda

I'm trying to make a post request from a webpage to a `Wildfly Camunda` server to start a task. It works using postman with `localhost:8080/engine-rest/message`, but when I use the webpage all I get is `Type error: failed to fetch`. I have tried just using `localhost:8080/engine-rest/message` but gets:

```json
Fetch API cannot load localhost:8080/engine-rest/message. URL scheme must be "HTTP" or "HTTPS" for CORS request.

/* And */

Error: TypeError: Failed to fetch at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous>
```

And if I set mode : `no-cors` I get `Fetch API cannot load localhost:8080/engine-rest/message. URL scheme "localhost" is not supported.` and `Error: TypeError: Failed to fetch at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous>`

```js
const form = document.getElementById('myForm');

form.addEventListener('submit', function() {
 //   alert("Request sent");
    const urlHttp = 'http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/message';
    const url = "localhost:8080/engine-rest/message";
    const data = {
        messageName: 'start',
        businessKey: '7'
    };

    // send POST request
    fetch(urlHttp, {
        method: 'POST',
      //  mode : 'no-cors',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;  charset=UTF-8;',
           // 'Accept' : 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log('Success:', data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });

});
```